# Cannot stop or even kill tomcat process

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

I started a `tomcat` service through `./catalina.sh start` and now that I want to stop/kill it - it won't do so.

When I started it with the script, I had 2 processes:

```
my-user   2728   2.2  0.8  4480236 138448 s001  S     9:52AM   0:01.82 "some -Djava configurations and executables"
my-user   2737   0.0  0.0  2434840    800 s001  S+    9:53AM   0:00.00 grep tomcat
```

When I run `./catalina.sh stop` (or `./shutdown.sh`) - it will stop only the first process. Then for the other one I try `pkill -9 -f tomcat` but it doesn't do the trick. And the process changes its PID basically every second, so I can't try to kill it by PID either.

Trying to shut it down through the shutdown scripts again throws an exception:

```
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

Comment: Is your tomcat a clustering environment?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I figure that out? And what difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below command
    `sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[c]atalina' | awk '{print $2}')`

Let me know if it helps

Comment: For `'[c]atalina'` it gave me an error of wrong usage of `kill`, so I changed it to just `'catalina'`, but it didn't work - I get `kill: <some PID>: No such process`. Same with when I try to grep for `'tomcat'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command which kill all processes resulted in grep.

ps -Af | grep "tomcat" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs kill -9

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have got the output:

```
my-user   2728   2.2  0.8  4480236 138448 s001  S     9:52AM   0:01.82 "some -Djava configurations and executables"
my-user   2737   0.0  0.0  2434840    800 s001  S+    9:53AM   0:00.00 grep tomcat
```

... from the command `ps aux | grep tomcat`

The first line is your Tomcat process. The second line is **the grep you have just started**.

This explains why the PID "changes every second" (it's changes every time, since it's a new `grep`), and why you can't kill it after seeing its output.

Prove this by running (for example) `ps aux | grep i_do_not_expect_to_find_this`

One neat trick to avoid this is to make one char of your grep pattern a character class:

```
$ ps aux | grep [t]omcat
```

Because this regex matches "tomcat" but does not match "[t]omcat", the `ps | grep` will no longer see its own grep.

Other than that, from your description it sounds as if `./catalina.sh stop` is working correctly. It works by making a socket connection to an admin port belonging to Tomcat, and requesting a shutdown. This explains why you get a `Connection refused` exception when the process has already stopped.